# Find a shared time (overlap) in time columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I'm trying to find a shared time where two datetime columns representing a start and an end time overlap with other records.

for example if we have these two columns:

```
Start                    End 
2016-08-22 20:20:00      2016-08-22 20:30:00   
2016-08-22 20:55:00      2016-08-22 21:53:00   
2016-08-22 21:38:00      2016-08-22 21:58:00
```

I want to check the overlap between them, the output would be:

```
 Start                    End                   Overlap
2016-08-22 20:20:00      2016-08-22 20:30:00    NaN
2016-08-22 20:55:00      2016-08-22 21:53:00   2016-08-22 21:38:00
2016-08-22 21:38:00      2016-08-22 21:58:00   2016-08-22 21:38:00
```

is there an efficient way to achieve it?

Comment: Could you please explain why `2016-08-22 21:38:00` on both cases?

Comment: @yatu because it is the date where the both columns share.

Comment: As I understand it  rows 1 and 2 share time from `2016-08-22 21:38:00 ` to `2016-08-22 21:53:00`

Comment: @yatu Yes row 2 and 3m as it is in the range of the previous record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach. You could define the following function:

```
def common_row(x):
    rows = df.loc[df.index != x.name,:]
    s = [min(x.End -y.Start, y.End - x.Start).total_seconds() > 0 for 
             y in rows.itertuples()]
    shared = rows.index[s].values
    if shared.size > 0:
        return df.loc[shared[0], 'Start']
```

What it does is look for other rows with time overlap and assigns the time in `Start` from the overlapping row (which will not be the current row, as your sample output suggests).

If you apply this along `axis 1` you get:

```
df['Overlap'] = df.apply(lambda x: common_row(x), axis=1)

         Start                 End             Overlap
0 2016-08-22 20:20:00 2016-08-22 20:30:00                 NaT
1 2016-08-22 20:55:00 2016-08-22 21:53:00 2016-08-22 21:38:00
2 2016-08-22 21:38:00 2016-08-22 21:58:00 2016-08-22 20:55:00
```

---

If what you want is to have the index of the row with time overlapping you can instead use:

```
def common_row(x):
    rows = df.loc[df.index != x.name,:]
    s = [min(x.End -y.Start, y.End - x.Start).total_seconds() > 0 for 
             y in rows.itertuples()]
    shared = rows.index[s].values
    if shared.size > 0:
        return int(shared[0])
```

Which will in this case give:

```
df['Overlap'] = df.apply(lambda x: common_row(x), axis=1)
          Start                 End          Overlap
0 2016-08-22 20:20:00 2016-08-22 20:30:00      NaN
1 2016-08-22 20:55:00 2016-08-22 21:53:00      2.0
2 2016-08-22 21:38:00 2016-08-22 21:58:00      1.0
```

Comment: Did this not help @shahad?